# Give 1 Html Option 2 Names?

Tags: html, forms, html-select

What's happening is that I'm using a payment processor not under my control, and I need to pass it the values of shipping, and the values of shipping per additional item.
Since they're packaged separate, we're going to charge the same amount per additional item, so instead of coming up with two identical fields that the user has to fill out, I'm trying to create one field that assigns the value of shippingf and shipping2f

Below is an example of one of my many attempts. Another attempt has been just putting name="" twice, and that didn't seem to work either.

```
<select name="shippingf, shipping2f" style="height:35px;">

  <option value="12">US</option>

  <option value="32">Canada</option>

</select>
```

any help on this matter would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that.  Consider using Javascript with a hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with just HTML.

You could either

1. use JS to change the value of a `type="hidden"` element in the form, or
2. server-side (assuming PHP), before you `include` your payment processor, add `$_POST['shipping2f'] = $_POST['shippingf'];`. Just keep `shippingf` in the HTML.

---

Since the OP said option 2 won't work, here's an example for option 1:

HTML:

```
<select name="shippingf" style="height:35px;">
    <option value="12">US</option>
    <option value="32">Canada</option>
</select>
<input name="shipping2f" type="hidden"></input>
```

jQuery:

```
$("select[name=shippingf]").change(function(){
    $("input[name=shipping2f]").val($(this).children(':selected:first').val());
}).change();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nb8j06qb/

## *or* <====

HTML:

```
<select id='sf' name="shippingf" style="height:35px;">
    <option value="12">US</option>
    <option value="32">Canada</option>
</select>
<input id='s2f' name="shipping2f" type="hidden" value="12"></input>
```

**Vanilla JS:**

```
document.getElementById('sf').onmouseup = function(){
    document.getElementById('s2f').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nb8j06qb/1/

Comment: Didn't thought about solution 2, smart one!

Comment: "processor not under my control" Option two would be fantastic, if it was an option.

Comment: @user3821353 Updated with JS option. The server-side option is cleaner so I recommend using it whenever possible. If you were using `include` to get your processor, you'd just need the one line (`$_POST['shipping2f'] = $_POST['shippingf'];`) before it.

Comment: It worked like an absolute dream. Thank you so much for being so incredibly detailed in your response, and the demo was definitely easy for me to grasp and understand the concept. I agree that the server side is probably a heck of a lot cleaner (I'm a fan of PHP over Javascript any day anyway), but unfortunately I don't even see it as an option for me. :/ Thanks again!

Comment: @user3821353 Great. Did you using jQuery or vanilla? I do hope this is being validated server-side, as the developer tools can be used to change the value of the hidden input.

Comment: I used vanilla, didn't want to load the jQuery library, seemed like more trouble than it was worth for the same thing...maybe?

Comment: @user3821353 Definitely not worth loading jQuery for just this.